# How to check if a certain part of a string is in a set of strings in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

If I have a list of strings

```
set1 = ['\\land','\\lor','\\implies']
```

I want to scan a list of strings and check whether any of the strings contain the set elements within them.

The string `'\land'` would return true for being in set1

However, how would I check whether `'(\lor'` is in set1?

Comment: what have you tried? Technically `set1` is a `list`, not `set`. And `\land` is not in `set1`, unless you look for some partial/fuzzy match. Nor list elements are in `\land` string. In this case you need to clarify your question/provide more info.

Comment: I'm confused... `(\lor` isn't in `set1` but one of the items in `set1` is in `(\lor`. Is that what you mean? Then `any(s in "(\\lor" for s in set1)` would do.

Comment: Yeah you're right, it's a list. However '\land' is in set1 because,  '\\land' is how Python will store '\land'.

Comment: @tdelaney , basically I want strings like '(\lor', 'xyz\lor' and '))\lor' to return true for being in set1 because the strings contain '/lor', which is an element of set1.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, I overlooked the escape sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
import re

set1 = ['\\land','\\lor','\\implies']
strings = ['\land', '(\lor']

r = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(w) for w in set1]), flags=re.I)

for i in strings:
    print(r.findall(i))
```

The output of this is

```
['\\land']
['\\lor']
```

**** Modification - if there is one string**

```
import re

set1 = ['\\land','\\lor','\\implies']
strings = '(\lor'

r = re.compile('|'.join([re.escape(w) for w in set1]), flags=re.I)

print(r.findall(strings))
```

** if you just want the special character "(" to be out from "(\lor" we could do that by this :

```
>>> a = '(\lor'
>>> a.split('(')[1]
'\\lor'
```

Comment: Thank you, how would I alter this if I was to just check one string instead of a list of strings?

Comment: Do you know how I could split the string in to two parts as well? If I had '(\lor' how could I get '(' and '\\lor'

Comment: @Biggeez, I have updated the answer, see if this is what you needed

Comment: More specifically, if I had  ````'Predicate(big,small)'````  string, how could I split that up in to a list of size six; ````['Predicate','(','big','small',')']````